# How to write the positive and Negative test cases of same scenario in java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testcase, sdlc

I want to write the both test cases whether positive scenario and negative scenario.

My sample code is,

```
    /**
     * 
     */
    public void testgetAsnAccuracyInstanceType() throws Exception
    {
        String METHOD_NAME = "testgetAsnAccuracyInstanceType";
        log.entering(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);

         //Rating Element "1" ASN Accuracy
         populateForTestMethodValues("1");
         populateWeekOfList();
         List<WeeklyDeliveryInstanceTypeQO> asnAccuracyInstanceTypeList = weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportForm.getAsnAccuracyInstanceType();
         assertTrue("testgetASNAccuracyRatingElement is Not Empty: ", asnAccuracyInstanceTypeList.size() > 0);
         log.exiting(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear how you expect us to be able to help you without any information about what your method is meant to do.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you not know how to use JUnit at all, or is there some more specific issue?

Comment: weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportForm.getAsnAccuracyInstanceType() this is my method.

Comment: @jon skeet how to write the negative test case for this test case instead of positive test case

Comment: Again, without knowing what the method is meant to do, it's impossible to say what a negative test would look like. The fact that it has no parameters means that the normal negative tests of invalid arguments don't apply, but you may want to consider what would happen if the test data didn't exist.

Comment: @jon skeet i can't post my code it shows the code isnot formatted. but i clicked the code button it doesn't upload it. i don't know what can i do

Comment: You cannot create both test cases(negative and positive) for all scenarios.
And creation will depend on what exactly you are dealing with.

Comment: Well you don't even need to post the code - you can *describe* what it's meant to do. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

To assert it works:

```
// use input data you expect results for
assertFalse("testgetASNAccuracyRatingElement is empty", 
    asnAccuracyInstanceTypeList.isEmpty());
```

To assert the negative case:

```
// use input data you don't expect results for
assertTrue("testgetASNAccuracyRatingElement is not empty", 
    asnAccuracyInstanceTypeList.isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
assertTrue("testgetASNAccuracyRatingElement is Not Empty: ", 
           asnAccuracyInstanceTypeList.size() > 0);
```

is strictly equivalent to:

```
assertFalse("testgetASNAccuracyRatingElement is Not Empty: ", 
           asnAccuracyInstanceTypeList.isEmpty());
```

(if that was what you were asking)

Answer (score 0):

Input/Test data decides if the test case is for positive or negative case.

So just have two test methods (one for positive and another for negative) and call with positive and negative data respectively.